AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002250a40> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
so i have a wav file that i am able to play just fine on my mac. I am currently trying to write a C++ program that uses miniaudio https://miniaud.io/index.html to play wav files but my program is just displaying this error and exiting and no audio is played
2024-11-06 23:32:56.413181-0800 tts[15549:33644092] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002250a40> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46 

the code that i have is just the referenced code specified in the miniaudio.h to play a simple playback https://miniaud.io/docs/examples/simple_playback.html and my code is as below
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"
...
void data_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount){
 ma_decoder* pDecoder = (ma_decoder*)pDevice->pUserData;
 if (pDecoder == NULL) {
      return;
  }

 ma_decoder_read_pcm_frames(pDecoder, pOutput, frameCount, NULL);

(void)pInput;
}

void process() {
    
  ma_result result;
  ma_decoder decoder;
  ma_device_config deviceConfig;
  ma_device device;
    
  result = ma_decoder_init_file("<path to wav file>", NULL, &decoder);
  if (result != MA_SUCCESS) {
        return;
  }
    
  deviceConfig = ma_device_config_init(ma_device_type_playback);
  deviceConfig.playback.format   = decoder.outputFormat;
  deviceConfig.playback.channels = decoder.outputChannels;
  deviceConfig.sampleRate        = decoder.outputSampleRate;
  deviceConfig.dataCallback      = data_callback;
  deviceConfig.pUserData         = &decoder;
    
  if (ma_device_init(NULL, &deviceConfig, &device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
      ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
      return;
  }
    
  if (ma_device_start(&device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
      ma_device_uninit(&device);
      ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
      return;
  }
    
  ma_device_uninit(&device);
  ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
}

reading other threads seem to suggest this might be a hardware issue but i am entirely not sure, so want to see if i can get any pointers to resolve this issue and also confirmation that this is a hardware issue and has nothing to do with my progra or miniaudio.
---Update---------------
I am only seeing the error in debug, when i run without debug i do not see the error but still no audio. Also i did put break point in all the error cases where we are returning and no break points are getting hit so it seems like all invocation like ma_device_init and ma_device_start are succeeding.
-----Second Update-------------------
i am able to hear the audio if i put a sleep after ma_device_start. I was assuming that the api would not return before the playback was complete but seems like that was not the correct understanding. This logic was i one of the examples provided by miniaudio themselves but still it is not not working out of the box. Can anyone familiar with miniaudio tell what other mechanism do i have to wait until the playback is completed before quiting the application rather than sleeping.
if (ma_device_start(&device) != MA_SUCCESS) {
        ma_device_uninit(&device);
        ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);
        return;
    }

    sleep(10);

    ma_device_uninit(&device);
    ma_decoder_uninit(&decoder);


Why did you change int main (like in the example) to void process? Now it just takes longer to copy-paste and reproduce.

@pptaszni its a c++ application and one of the class needs to play a wav file and therefore i had the logic to play the wav file inside that class.

Unfortunately cannot repro, so it might be indeed some unsupported HW.

@pptaszni so is my understanding correct that you are able to play a wav file with this code. I did update the description i did put breakpoint in all the error conditions but no hit it seems like ma_device_init and ma_device_start are succeeding.

Well, I added small sleep in the end of the program to actually hear the wav (I don't know this library, but there should be a proper way to do it), but yes, it works for me on windows and WSL2.

@pptaszni can i ask whats made you put a sleep. I am also new to this library and first time trying audio playback but by adding a 10 sec sleep i am able to hear the audio. Its just that i would have assumed that the api was such that it will not return until the playback was completed, but seems like that is not the right understanding as ideally there should be some other mechanism rather than sleeping, so just curious what made you put the sleep in the first case

Simply noticed that program terminates successfully too fast, and my sample wav is 3s long. Also miniaudio debug prints were suggesting that wav file parameters are recognized correctly. But yep, somewhere in the docs it must be explained how to correctly async-wait for the sound to finish playing.

@bourne I'm familiar with this library and yes, you have to manually keep your program alive while outputting audio. This is accomplished in the reference code with the getchar() call, which keeps the program alive until you press "enter" and then deinitializes. I'm not sure why you removed it. An alternative to getchar() is to have your code enter a while loop until some exit condition is met.
